# I need to declare a 4x4 matrix containing a vector of integers

Tags: c++, arrays, vector

I need to declare a 4x4 matrix containing a vector of integers. I think the matrix is a multidimensional array but then I am confused if I need to do [4][4] and/or when to use the < vector > int() syntax.

Answer (score 3):

If the dimensions of the matrix are known at compile time, use `std::array`.

```
using Matrix = std::array<std::array<int, M>, N>;
Matrix matrix;
```

If the dimensions of the matrix are known only at run time, use `std::vector`.

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> matrix(m, std::vector<int>(n));
```

Answer (score 0):

it might be an answer if u just wanna declare 4x4 vector.

```
vector<int> _v[4][4];
```

Comment: is _v the name of the array?

Comment: @Welshie321 yes.

Comment: This declares a two dimensional array of vectors. A 3d construct.

Answer (score 0):

The most direct is

```
typedef std::array<std::array<int, 4>, 4> Matrix;
Matrix m;
```

But yeah, you could use `vector`'s, if you want rows of variable length. Or `int[16]` if you want it very low-level.

Comment: At this early stage in the class we're allowed to code by "using namespace std". What would the code be without the std? Also, what is the name of the array in your example above? Can you change the name to something that is not "array" for clarity?

Comment: The same, just without the `std::`.

Comment: No, you can't change the array name as it is the class name in the standard.